# Styling the AppCompat Spinner background color

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm trying to make a simple theme extending from AppCompat and I want to change the background color of a Spinner's pop-up. I can get pretty far in completely restyling AppCompat purely by using colors, but got stuck on the Spinner.

Inspecting the xml for `Widget.AppCompat.Spinner`, I see that its `android:popupBackground` is a 9-patch bitmap for API 20 and lower, but a vector drawable for 21 and higher. I know how to create a tinted 9-patch.

For 21+, the spinner background is defined in `popup_background_material.xml` as:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
            android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid
            android:color="?attr/colorPopupBackground" />

</shape>
```

I tried setting this color attribute in my `values-v21` style like this:

```xml
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="MyBaseTheme">
        <item name="android:colorPopupBackground">@color/colorSpinnerBackground</item>
    </style>
```

But at build time there is an error:

```
AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/colorPopupBackground' is private.
```

Is there some simpler way of recoloring Spinners that I'm missing? I know I could copy-paste the vector xml file and change the color there, but I'd prefer to stick to colors only so if there are changes to AppCompat's theming, I can get them automatically by updating its version.

Currently using AppCompat 1.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

I have a good example about custom spinner.

This example show how to change spinner background color.

but it is korean, not english

see link.

https://blog.naver.com/jinhan38/222094163563

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I know how to create my own drawable and set it as a background. I want to know if it's possible to tint the existing shape drawable in the style without having to create a new drawable where the shape has to be defined.